# Selenium2: Obtaining error details when using executeScript() fails

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

In order to deal with some browser peculiarities, I find myself needing to send javascript commands during tests.

Sometimes I get an error back from Selenium saying there was a javascript error but the server did not provide any details.  Is there a way to get more information to see what's failing?

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browser you are executing your scripts on, you may be able to see the details in the JavaScript error console. For IE, this setting is inside `Tools > Advanced > Display a notification about every script error`. Even with this disabled, there should be an error icon in the lower left of the browser that, if clicked, should provide more information on the JavaScript error.